# putting jquery buttons in clistview widget in yii

Tags: jquery-ui, yii

I am trying to put a button which will be displayed along with some data in the view file I specified in "itemView" field of the CListView widget, but instead of the styled button for every list item, I am just getting it or the first list item. My code in the _view file is:

```
<div id="listView">
<div class="thedata">
  ...some data
</div>

<div id="buttons">
<?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiButton', array(
'buttonType'=>'button',
'name'=>'btnJobs',
'caption'=>'Manage Jobs',
'options'=>array('icons'=>'js:{primary:"ui-icon-wrench"}'),
'onclick'=>'js:function(){alert("Manage Jobs clicked."); this.blur(); return false;}',
));
?>
</div>
</div>
```

and the code for CListView widget is just the bare minimum:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_view'
));
```

any suggestions?

Comment: In addition to what @thaddeusmt posted, although not exactly related to your question, i would suggest you to name the **button div** as a class instead of an id, specifically use `<div class="button">` instead of `<div id="button">`, for the same reason that ids should be unique.
Also change the `<div id="listview">` to `<div class="listview">`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try passing in a unique ID to the CJuiButton, like so:

```
<?php 
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiButton', array(
  'id'=>'button'.$data->id, // add a unique ID here (could use $index instead of $data->id)
  'buttonType'=>'button',
  'name'=>'btnJobs',
  'caption'=>'Manage Jobs',
  'options'=>array('icons'=>'js:{primary:"ui-icon-wrench"}'),
  'onclick'=>'js:function(){alert("Manage Jobs clicked."); this.blur(); return false;}',
 ));
?>
```

The problem is that since all of your buttons have the same 'name' (and therefore 'id') jQuery is only binding to the first one. Making sure each button has a unique ID should fix this, so jQuery will bind correctly.

Comment: +1 good. And we can also just append the `$index` to the `'name'=>'btnJobs'.$index` property instead of using the `'id'` property explicitly, this ofcourse depends on the final application of the buttons, if they are performing the same kind of function then they can have the same name, am i right? Btw, if we append only to name, then id and name end up being the same value.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you could just make sure the name is unique, which would make the id unique also. I'm not sure what the drawbacks or benefits would be to having unique names instead of the same name on every button.

Comment: Thanks guys! that worked just fine... just had to make sure that the "name" property was unique for every button.